# upload video to youtube using curl

Tags: curl

I am trying to upload video to youtube.com from local server.

Video is uploaded to youtube if I use the form below. I am able to fetch the response from youtube after login and adopt the response in the form below.

```
        <form action="<?php echo( $response->url ); ?>?nexturl=<?php echo( urlencode( $nexturl ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p class="block">
                <label>Upload Video</label>
                <span class="youtube-input">
                    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
                </span>                        
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo( $response->token ); ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Video" />
        </form>
```

But If try to do the same with curl as below then it doesnt work .. Any suggestions ??

```
                $file_name_with_full_path = $video_path; //$video_path is like /path/to/abc.mp4                    
                $post = array('file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path, 'token' => $response->token,);

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$response->url."?nexturl=".urlencode($nexturl));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
                $result=curl_exec ($ch);
                curl_close ($ch);
                echo $result;
                die();
```

Comment: please use as many relevant tags as possible in future

Comment: olrite! thanks . Neway thanks i used Zend for this and its solved now ..

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but I believe you can use the youtube API to upload videos now: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert